# Likeit module count for an entity refrence field in drupal 8

Tags: 8

I have Enabled the [Like it!](https://www.drupal.org/project/likeit) module for a content type called "**recipe**" on my website. I am able to get the value of like count for the recipe in node--recipe.html.twig. Now, in the same content type, I have an entity reference field for recommended recipes. I need to render the value of count for recommended recipes in my node--recipe.html.twig file. what changes are required and in which files please if anyone knows then help? I have very little idea about modules.

Using Drupal 8.5

> content['_field_layout']['content']['likeit']['#count']

gives me the value of count for recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [hook_preprocess_hook()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) and get the referenced entities values.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node__recipe(&$variables){
  kint($variables); 
}
```

For **kint()** you need to enable **devel kint** module.

Pass each entity like below:

```
$like_count = likeit_get_count($entity);
```

This will provide the likes of the entity that you have passed. Once you get the count pass it in your **node--recipe.html.twig**

Comment: I tried preprocessing the .theme file but an error occurs stating that get_likeit_count id() null. my recommended recipe field is a multi value field . three recommended recipes are shown for a recipe

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: themename_hook_preprocess function($variable){$like_count=likeit_get_count($entity)}}

Comment: i tried this my recipe node has field_recommended (entity refrence machine name) which have three recipes that are refrenced how can i pass these recipes to hook. I dumped $variable and it gave me all the nodes and not the current node for which i want recmmended recipes i have no idea about using hooks and searched google but still the concept is not clear .

Comment: sir your answer is correct iam able to call this function but i made a service in some other module . then from my template i passed the value of each refrenced entity. but my question is still same how can i do this using hooks kindly share

Comment: Updated answer..